# Are cURL calls secure using HTTPS?

Tags: php, api, security, curl, https

I am using cURL to call an API over HTTPS. Assuming the API is secured and the HTTPS connection is too, would a simple cURL call on my end be secure or do I need to change cURL parameters to make it secure or should I not use cURL at all?

Security is very important in this project.

Comment: Secure from what? HTTPS will secure the call from interception - "man in the middle" - attacks. It won't save you from bad code (stuff like not escaping/encoding user-submitted parameters that might be passed as data with the cURL request) or from someone reading your code and finding the API keys.

Comment: Okay, so I got three downvotes. It would be helpful to get some feedback with that. I ask questions to learn, I'm not a security expert. Anyways, @Daniel Stenberg seemed to have answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but I considered it due to the broad nature of the question. It's really only answerable with a close look at the code - there are many, many potential security pitfalls in making external HTTP requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

curl does HTTPS securely by default. Just make sure you **DO NOT** disable certificate verification with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`.

Comment: not quite sure if this means 1.  do not disable verification and the way to do that is by using ``CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`` or ``CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`` or 2. do not disable verification which is what will happen if you use ``CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`` or ``CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST``.

Comment: 1 or 2 hasn't made any difference for curl in a long time. Disabling is done when one or both of them are set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

They don't specify anything in docs about doing something extra for security (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html - Chapter 10 - HTTPS).

In case of using certificates, you should use a command like this:

**curl --cert mycert.pem https://secure.example.com**